# Example vs prompt question for placeholder copy

Tags: copywriting, ux-writing

I am often torn whenever I have to write a placeholder copy for form fields, especially if it is a long text box where we want to encourage users to elaborate their points (e.g. reviews, feedback, etc.)

Should the placeholder copy be a prompt question to help users elaborate more, or should it be an example? Currently, I'm leaning towards prompt questions because examples can be too assumptive. What do you guys think?